# Re-rendering app with custom hook not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seek advice regarding a small project I work on. I have a problem with re-rendering/reloading app when my state changes. The issue occurred when I changed useState to custom hook that uses session storage. There is the code of the hook:

```
const useStateWithSessionStorage = (localStorageKey) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(localStorageKey)) || {
      screen: "signin",
      loading: false,
      user: null,
      response: null,
    }
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};
```

and this is my App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useStateWithSessionStorage("appState");

  const renderApp = () => {
    if (appState.screen == "signin") return <Signin />;
    if (appState.screen == "hub") return <Hub />;
  };

 return <div className="App">{renderApp()}</div>;
}
```

I also tried to load screen value into another state, which would be re-rendered in useEffect, however, without success.

renderApp function returns either  or . Signin component shows only email and password input, which values are sent do flask endpoint working with sql.

That endpoint updates appState. Concretely it changes appState.screen to "hub".

There's the problem I mentioned. Although state changes (visibly on page displayed by JSON.stringify). The app wont re-render and stays on  component. To work properly and show  I always must refresh the page.

I'm fairly new into this, could anyone give me an advice, please?

Comment: That is because you are not updating the state in your custom hook. value doesn't change

Comment: Hi, I'm displaying the appState with JSON.stringify and it visibly changes.

Comment: But you aren't calling setValue from App component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to listen to [Window: storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) to get notified when some component changes the session key value:

```
const useStateWithSessionStorage = (localStorageKey) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(localStorageKey)) || {
      screen: "signin",
      loading: false,
      user: null,
      response: null,
    }
  );

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    const onStorage = () => {
       const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(localStorageKey)));
       if(data.screen !== value.screen) { /* data changes*/
          setValue(data);
       }
    }
    window.addEventListener('storage', onStorage);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", onStorage);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value]);

  

  return [value, setValue];
};
```